# Can i Rotate a button in android

Tags: android-layout

i am developing application in which you can place buttons, where you have the acess of placing them where ever you want.. its a kind of a game in which you build sculptures from buttons, well i want to add a feature of rotating every button with user's choice.. so
how can i rotate a button in android through coding...
like is there some kind of a function like rotate(angle);
i don't want to go with the XML format because i guess that is static we can not change its values while the program is running..
e.g i found it somewhere but this is static more over it rotate the whole layout but i just want r0tate one specific element..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="90"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="0"
android:duration="1200" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Animation ranim = (Animation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), 
        R.anim.rotation); 
buttonRotate.setAnimation(ranim);
```

Use your XML file instead of `R.anim.ratation`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:drawable="@drawable/mainmenu_background">
</rotate>
```

You can use this xml file and here is the java code

```
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotation);
rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
myView.startAnimation(rotation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much everything that is drawn on Android is extended from a View

Looking at the documentation it appears that you can rotate Views

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation%28float%29

However, this is only since API 11 which is Android 3.0

If you want to support lower API levels I might look at the Canvas class and actually "drawing" a button bitmap on that which you can also rotate.